# Action buttons to enter the quickActionBar GreenDroid

Tags: android, greendroid

I am creating an actionbar with greendroid. I managed to create the actionbar and then put a quick action. My problem is just about the quickaction because I do not know how to insert actions for each of the buttons quick action. Could anyone help me?
This picture explains better what I do:

http://s7.postimage.org/iavbl44mj/greendroid09.png

And this my code of quickActionBar

```
private void initQuickActionBar() {
        quickActions = new QuickActionBar(this);

        quickActions.addQuickAction(new QuickAction(this, R.drawable.buscar, "Buscar"));
        quickActions.addQuickAction(new QuickAction(this, R.drawable.tags, "Tags"));
        quickActions.addQuickAction(new QuickAction(this, R.drawable.mail, "Email"));

        quickActions.setOnQuickActionClickListener(new OnQuickActionClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onQuickActionClicked(QuickActionWidget widget, int position) {



            }
        });
```

Thks!

Comment: you need to add quickaction when you click on action bar buttons or what?

Comment: Friend, I need to insert an action button to quickActionBar. As explained in the picture, when I click the "Share" (which is in actionbar) quickActionBar will open with three options (Buscar, Tags, and Email). What I want is to put an action on the BUSCAR button. you get the idea?

Comment: hi did u succed on creating action bar use green droid? is so tell me that's so simple i have tutorial for you but written in french language did u understand french?

Comment: ys sir. pass me the link pls! but friend ... I want to know is very simple. I wonder how I, eg, call the login function on facebook when the User clicks a button on my quickAction. you know answer me?

Answer (score 1):

You have to use the method **onHandleActionBarItemClick**

```
@Override
    public boolean onHandleActionBarItemClick(ActionBarItem item, int position) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case LOCATE:
          //show toast
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
            "Vous avez cliquez sur le bouton LOCATE",
            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        break;

    case REFRESH:
          //show toast
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
            "Vous avez cliquez sur le bouton REFRESH",
            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        break;

    case SHARE:
         // show quicAction and then a toas
         quickActions.show(item.getItemView());
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
            "Vous avez cliquez sur le bouton SHARE",
            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        break;
    default:
        return super.onHandleActionBarItemClick(item, position);
    }

    return true;
    }
```

in your activity you should have something simular to this

```
import greendroid.app.GDActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class GDIntroActivity extends GDActivity {

   private QuickActionWidget quickActions;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

   setActionBarContentView(R.layout.main);
   initActionBar();
   initQuickActionBar();
   }

private void initQuickActionBar() {
    quickActions = new QuickActionBar(this);
    quickActions.addQuickAction(new QuickAction(this, R.drawable.facebook,
        "Facebook"));
    quickActions.addQuickAction(new QuickAction(this, R.drawable.twitter, "Twitter"));
    quickActions.addQuickAction(new QuickAction(this, R.drawable.mail, "Email"));
    quickActions.setOnQuickActionClickListener(new OnQuickActionClickListener() {
        public void onQuickActionClicked(QuickActionWidget widget,
            int position) {
         Toast.makeText(GDIntroActivity.this,
         "Item " + position + " clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
         .show();
        }
    });
    }
}
```

Check this [link](http://www.tutos-android.com/introduction-greendroid)
if you want to lunch facebook login you can use this

```
Intent intent = new Intent("android.intent.category.LAUNCHER");
intent.setClassName("com.facebook.katana", "com.facebook.katana.LoginActivity");
startActivity(intent);
```

But the facebook app must be installed on your device or your emulator to trigger it

you can use it in your QuickAction Like this

```
private void initQuickActionBar() {
        quickActions = new QuickActionBar(this);
        quickActions.addQuickAction(new QuickAction(this, R.drawable.facebook,
            "Facebook"));
        quickActions.addQuickAction(new QuickAction(this, R.drawable.twitter, "Twitter"));
        quickActions.addQuickAction(new QuickAction(this, R.drawable.mail, "Email"));
        quickActions.setOnQuickActionClickListener(new OnQuickActionClickListener() {
            public void onQuickActionClicked(QuickActionWidget widget,
                int position) {
             switch(position){
              case facebook_position:
                   Intent intent = new Intent("android.intent.category.LAUNCHER");
                   intent.setClassName("com.facebook.katana", "com.facebook.katana.LoginActivity");
                   startActivity(intent);
                   break;
              case twitter_position:
                //do stuff

             }
            }
    });
    }
```

Comment: Ok but that does not answer my question. I want to know, e.g., inside the method "initQuickAction," how do I click on the facebook he calls the login method facebook. you know how to do it?

Comment: you want when user cliks on item of QuicAction do some stuff?

Comment: if he clicks on facebbok icon you lunch facebook app for exemple?

Comment: ys. I want that when clicked, opens the facebook login. I already have the method for this. I just need to know how to invoke it within the quickAction.

Comment: use a switch inside the ononQuickActionClicked of your initQuickActionBar()

switch(clicked-position){
case 1: //do something
case 2: //do something else

Comment: but I have to call an intent? Because I have a method called (init) that he used to log into facebook. I just want to grab this button, put it inside the quickAction and set his action when clicked, or when they click the button "Login" he must call the "init".

Comment: bro, my biggest problem is because he rides a quickActionBar you through a drawable. Only the button I want to put in quickAction is a login button that has a dual behavior. (If you are not logged in facebook button appears "Login" if you're logged in it says "Logout." For that I use "R. id.login." As I call it within the quickaction?